# Create a macro inside a new created workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have workbooks that I create and copy values to, from one master spreadsheet. The only problem I'm having is that I can't limit the scroll area because the scroll area doesn't save upon being closed. Is there a way I can make a macro inside each new workbook which limits the scroll area whenever the new workbooks that are created are opened? Here is what I have right now:

```
Sub ProgramExport()
  'Dim arr

  'arr3 = Array("Accessible Pedestrian Signals", "Advanced Traffic Signal Control ", "Bathurst Street Bridge Rehabilitation ", "C.I. Centennial Pk Path", _
               "C.I. Etobicoke Valley PK", "C.I. Humber Trail Extension and Gaps", "C.I. Pan Am Trail Expansion - Gatineau Trail", _
               "City Bridge Rehabilitation ", "City-10-Surface Transit Operational Improvement Studies - Phase 3", _
               "City-11-King Street Modelling Study", "City-12-REimagining Yonge North Study", "City-15-Flemingdon Park-Thorncliffe Park Neighbourhood  Cycling Connections", _
               "City-22-Accessible Pedestrian Signals Expansion", "City-26-Geometric Safety Improvements - Removal of Channelized Right Turns", _
               "City-27-Missing sidewalk links - 2017", "City-28-Missing sidewalk links - 2018", "City-37-Installation of Cycling Facilites on Woodbine Ave.", _
               "City-38-Installation of Cycling Facilities on Lakeshore Blvd West", "City-39-Surface Transit Operational Improvement Studies - Phase 1", _
               "City-40-King Street Pilot Implementation", "City-42-Yonge Tomorrow", "City-6-Eglinton Connects Streetscape Improvements and Cycle Tracks", _
               "City-8-East Don Trail", "City-9-Surface Transit Operational Improvement Studies - Phase 2", "Critical Interim Road Rehabilitation ", _
               "Cycling Infrastructure ", "Design of Cherry St Realignment and Bridges", "Ditch Rehabilitation and Culvert Reconstruction", _
               "Don Valley Parkway Rehabilitation", "Engineering Studies", "F.G. Gardiner Interim Repairs", "Facility Improvements ", _
               "Georgetown South City Infrastructure Upgrades", "Greenville and Yonge Street Improvements", _
               "Growth Related Capital Works ", "Guide Rail Replacement Program", "John Street Revitalization Project", "King Liberty Cycling Pedestrian Bridge", _
               "Laneways", "LARP (Lawrence-Allen Revitalization Project) Phase 1", "LED signal Module Conversion ", "Legion Road Extension & Grade Separation", _
               "Local Road Rehabilitation", "Local Speed Limit Reduction", "Major Roads Rehabilitation", "Major SOGR Pooled Contingency ", _
               "N.I. Mill Street Streetscape", "N.I. The Queensway from Islington to Royal York", "Neighborhood Improvements", _
               "North York Service Road Extension", "Pedestrian Safety and Infrastructure Program", _
               "Port Union Road ( Lawrence Ave - Kingston Rd)", "PSI Homewood Depressed Curb", "PXO Visibility Enhancement", _
               "Regent Park Revitalization ", "Retaining Walls Rehabilitation ", "Road Safety Plan (LGTSI) ", "Rouge National Park ", _
               "Salt Management Program", "Sidewalks", "Signs and Markings Asset Management", "Six Points Interchange Redevelopment", _
               "SM Bay Cloverdale", "SM McGill-Granby Village", "SM The Upper Avenue", "Steeles Widenings ( Tapscott Road - Beare Road) ", _
               "System Enhancements for Road Repair & Permits", "Tactile Domes Installation", "Third Party Signals ", "Traffic - Control RESCU", _
               "Traffic Calming", "Traffic Congestion Management ", _
               "Traffic Signals Major Modifications", "Transportation Safety & Local Improvement Program ", "Work for TTC & Others", _
               "Yonge Street Revitalization EA Study (Reimagining Yonge)")

  Dim Program As Range
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wbThis As Workbook
  Dim newBook As Workbook
  Dim value As String
  Dim userID As String
  Dim fn As String
  Dim programN As Variant
  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim sName As String
  userID = InputBox("Please enter your user id.")

  'For Each programN In arr3
      programN = "Local Road Rehabilitation"
      Set Program = Range("C1:C2000")
      Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
      'UserForm1.Show
      Set wbThis = Workbooks("TS L2L3v111.xlsm")
      Dim test As Worksheet: Set test = wbThis.Worksheets(4)
      'value = InputBox("Please enter the program you'd like to export.")
      fn = "C:\Users\" & userID & "\Desktop\" & programN & ".xlsx"
      'aFN = "C:\Users\ashaikh5\Desktop\Copy of TS L2L3v11.xlsm"
      newBook.SaveAs (fn)
      'FileFormat:=52

      For i = 1 To 2000
         If test.Cells(i, 3) = programN Then
                If rng Is Nothing Then
                    Set rng = test.Range(test.Cells(i, 1), test.Cells(i, 100))
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, test.Range(test.Cells(i, 1), test.Cells(i, 100)))
                End If
         Else
             'something
         End If

      Next i

      'For Each Cell In Program

          'If Cell = programN Then
              'If rng Is Nothing Then
                'Set rng = Cell.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 78))
              'Else
                'r = ActiveCell.Row
                'Set rng = Union(rng, Cell.Range(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1), Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 78)))
              'End If
          'Else
              'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3

      'End If

      'Next
      Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = newBook.Worksheets(1)
      erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
      If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.Copy
      Else
        MsgBox "rng was not set in the for loop"
      End If
      ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial
      'ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
      'ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      ws.Columns("A:L").ColumnWidth = 14
      ws.Columns("C").AutoFit
      ws.Columns("N:CM").ColumnWidth = 14
      'Set wbThis = Workbooks("TS L2L3v111.xlsm")

      'Dim test As Worksheet: Set test = wbThis.Worksheets(4)

      test.Range("A2:CV2").Copy
      ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
      ws.Columns("F:K").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("F:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("R:Z").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("R:Z").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("AH:AP").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("AH:AP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("AX:BF").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("AX:BF").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("BJ:BN").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("BJ:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Columns("BP:CA").Columns.Group
      ws.Columns("BP:CA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
      ws.Range("A1", "CM1").End(xlUp).AutoFilter 1
      ActiveWindow.SplitColumn = 13
      ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
      ActiveWindow.Zoom = 80
      'ws.Columns("CW:FX").Clear
      ws.Cells.Validation.Delete
      ws.ScrollArea = "A1:CV2000"
      newBook.Save
      newBook.Close

  'Next programN
End Sub
```

Comment: You can save the macro as an addin to the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART folder, which will allow every workbook which opens to run it.  I would recommend creating a quickribbon button tied to said macro so you can run it when needed.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really want every workbook that I open to run the macro though. As you can see, I'm only copying values from A to CV. For some reason, the workbook that is created goes from A to FU. I'm not sure about the reason behind that. That way I wouldn't have to limit the scroll area, if just goes to CV.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. All I had to do was paste the formatting with the headers. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you solved your question yourself, in case anyone finds this in future - the easiest solution to adding code to a newly created workbook is to base the new workbook on a macro-enabled template that already holds the desired code. So instead of

```
 Set wb = workbooks.new
```

use

```
Set wb = workbooks.new("c:\somedir\mytemplate.xltm")
```